# How to check that variable exists in Caché Object Script?

Tags: intersystems-cache

Is there a more elegant way in COS just to check that variable is set?

The tricky one I can guess is the next one:

```
set test = ""
write $get(test, "NO") '= "NO"
```

But the `test` variable can also be equal to `"NO"`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$Data(var)` for that. [Documentation](https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_fdata).

Comment: That's it! Thank you!